# Conditional statement in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

This is my models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=32,blank=True)
    name = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Organisation(models.Model):  
    user        = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='organisation_user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    members     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='organisation_members',blank=True)
```

I want to create a condition in my template that if member in the `manytomany` field is already there it will be shown `Already added` or else `Add Member` link and I want to do it in the profile list view template.

So I have done the following in my template:

```
{% for prof in profile %}
    {% if member in prof.name.organisation_user.members %}
        <a href="{% url 'userprofile:add_member' pk=prof.pk %}" class="btn btn-info" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Already added</a>
    {% else %}
       <a href="{% url 'userprofile:add_member' pk=prof.pk %}" class="btn btn-info" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add member</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

**Update**

I have done the following:

```
{% for prof.name in prof.name.organisation_members.all %}
   {% if prof.name %}
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Already added</a>
   {% else %}
       <a href="{% url 'userprofile:add_member' pk=prof.pk %}" class="btn btn-info" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Add member</a>
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

But now the else part is not running...

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: What condition should I write in my if statement in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done the below logic and it works fine:

```
{% for prof in profile %}
    {% if prof.Name.organisation_members.all %}
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Already added</a>
    {% else %}
       <a href="{% url 'userprofile:add_member' pk=prof.pk %}" class="btn btn-info" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Add member</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
    {% for prof in profile %}
        {% if prof.name.organisation_members == None %}
           <a href="{% url 'userprofile:add_member' pk=prof.pk %}" class="btn btn-info" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add member</a>
        {% else %}
           <a href="{% url 'userprofile:add_member' pk=prof.pk %}" class="btn btn-info" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Already added</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```